# How To perform calculations on array and show it in tabular form

Tags: php, html

I have an assignment regarding multiplication of array and show it in tabular form, my teacher just give me the data that is in the array form and said to display it in tabular form and also multiply the items **Quantity and price ** and show it in table ....i already have display the array in tabular form but i'm unable to product the QTY and price? anybody help ?

---

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$ProductsTest = array("1001" => array("Name" => "LCD","Desc" => "Sony","Qty" =>10,"Price" => 2000),
"1002" => array("Name" => "Mouse","Desc" => "Dell","Qty" =>3,"Price" => 300),
"1003" => array("Name" =>"Mouse","Desc" =>"a4Tech","Qty" =>3,"Price" =>300),
"1004" => array("Name" =>"USB","Desc" =>"Kingstton","Qty" =>15,"Price" =>700),
"1005" => array("Name" =>"HeadPhone","Desc" =>"a4Tech","Qty" =>7,"Price" =>3000));
$no_of_ele = count($ProductsTest);
echo '<br><br>';
echo ' <table border="2", bgcolor="white",width="100%"> 
<tr>
 <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Brand</th>
     <th>QTY</th> 
    <th>price</th>
    <th>totalamount</th>
  </tr>';
foreach( $ProductsTest as $values)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $values as $key )
    {
        echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
  }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

---

this is my output till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$ProductsTest = array("1001" => array("Name" => "LCD","Desc" => "Sony","Qty" =>10,"Price" => 2000),
"1002" => array("Name" => "Mouse","Desc" => "Dell","Qty" =>3,"Price" => 300),
"1003" => array("Name" =>"Mouse","Desc" =>"a4Tech","Qty" =>3,"Price" =>300),
"1004" => array("Name" =>"USB","Desc" =>"Kingstton","Qty" =>15,"Price" =>700),
"1005" => array("Name" =>"HeadPhone","Desc" =>"a4Tech","Qty" =>7,"Price" =>3000));
$no_of_ele = count($ProductsTest); 
?>
<br><br>
<table border="2", bgcolor="white",width="100%"> 
<tr>
 <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Brand</th>
     <th>QTY</th> 
    <th>price</th>
    <th>totalamount</th>
  </tr>
<?php
foreach( $ProductsTest as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['Name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['Desc'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['Qty'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['Price'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value['Qty']*$value['Price'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    $ProductsTest = array(
    "1001" => array("Name" => "LCD", "Desc" => "Sony", "Qty" =>10, "Price" => 2000),
    "1002" => array("Name" => "Mouse","Desc" => "Dell","Qty" =>3,"Price" => 300),
    "1003" => array("Name" =>"Mouse","Desc" =>"a4Tech","Qty" =>3,"Price" =>300),
    "1004" => array("Name" =>"USB","Desc" =>"Kingstton","Qty" =>15,"Price" =>700),
    "1005" => array("Name" =>"HeadPhone","Desc" =>"a4Tech","Qty" =>7,"Price" =>3000)
    );

    $no_of_ele = count($ProductsTest);

    echo '<br><br>';

    if( $no_of_ele > 0 )
    {
    echo '<table border="2", bgcolor="white",width="100%"> 
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th> 
    <th>Brand</th>
    <th>QTY</th> 
    <th>price</th>
    <th>totalamount</th>
    </tr>';

    foreach( $ProductsTest as $key_ProductsTest => $value_ProductsTest)
    {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$value_ProductsTest["Name"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value_ProductsTest["Desc"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value_ProductsTest["Qty"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value_ProductsTest["Price"].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. ($value_ProductsTest["Qty"] * $value_ProductsTest["Price"]) .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Sorry, no data found.";
    }


    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good soluction for this problem using functional programming you can map the array to return other array with the totalamount

```
    <!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    $lists = array("1001" => array("Name" => "LCD","Desc" => "Sony","Qty" =>10,"Price" => 2000),
    "1002" => array("Name" => "Mouse","Desc" => "Dell","Qty" =>3,"Price" => 300),
    "1003" => array("Name" =>"Mouse","Desc" =>"a4Tech","Qty" =>3,"Price" =>300),
    "1004" => array("Name" =>"USB","Desc" =>"Kingstton","Qty" =>15,"Price" =>700),
    "1005" => array("Name" =>"HeadPhone","Desc" =>"a4Tech","Qty" =>7,"Price" =>3000));

    $ProductsTest  = array_map(function($item){
        $item['totalamount'] = $item['Qty'] * $item['Price'];
        return $item;
    },$lists);
$no_of_ele = count($ProductsTest);
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo ' <table border="2", bgcolor="white",width="100%"> 
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th> 
        <th>Brand</th>
         <th>QTY</th> 
        <th>price</th>
        <th>totalamount</th>
      </tr>';
    foreach( $ProductsTest as $values)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach( $values as $key )
        {
            echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```